# NSView stopped clipping to bounds on macOS 14

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, appkit

I have a **macOS app** with `AppKit` that when building on the latest **Xcode**, `Xcode 15` and testing on `macOS 14` many elements of the UI seem wrong.

At first glance it seems as if they views stopped clipping to bounds when the used to do it, as in some cases I relied on this behaviour to show/hide buttons from a toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

## Clip to bounds

Starting on **macOS 14** and **Xcode 15** `NSView` has a new property: [clipsToBounds](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/4236466-clipstobounds#), similar to the one on `UIView` for `iOS`, but the difference is that on NSView there was nothing like this before.

Even if the documentation says this is available since `macOS 10.9+` I'm sure this was not there a few months ago, and behaviour changes too.

From the documentation:

> By default this value is false. In macOS 13 and earlier, the default
> value is true.

Not sure if this was covered on the **WWDC** and I just overlooked the update, but I can predict this will be breaking many `AppKit` apps.

To fix it and adopt the old behaviour is simple:

```swift
myNSView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: `clipsToBounds` is a private property in the macOS 13 SDK.

Comment: See [AppKit Release Notes for macOS 14](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/appkit-release-notes-for-macos-14) "For applications linked against the macOS 14 SDK, the default value of this property is false. Apps linked against older SDKs default to true."